# How do i merge two or more rows based on their foreign key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I have three tables which are:

```
A(a1, a2, a3)

//This tbl (Table) can have multiple instances of a1, but cause of its dependence on b1, 
//we have a unique record each time
B(b1, a1, b2)

//tbl C has a relationship with tbl B through b1. b1 can also have multiple instances, but 
//sometimes a number of unique records in this table can tie to just one record in the B tbl.
C(c1, b1, c2, c3)
```

Example:

```
//Table B sample data
b1     a1     b2
1      25     paper
2      29     pencil
3      29     parker

//Table C sample data
c1     b1     c2     c3
1      1      w      long
2      2      b      long
3      2      g      short
4      3      v      fat
```

Explanation:
For the record 2 in tbl B, records 2 and 3 in tbl C should form a single record for it.

From every thing so far, tbl A can have multiple records in tbl B which are distinct to tbl A. Tbl B can also have multiple  records in tbl C, but those multiple records must be merged into a single record (Where ever there is a duplicate foreign key in tbl C, then a merging should occur).

I hope i have done a good job at explaining my problem. I need a query to do this. Can anyone help please?

Addition #1:
In an effort to make it clearer i'll use the really situation im faced with.

Every drug is grouped under a main classification, sub classification, and a generic name.

```
-Main Classification
 -Sub Classification
  -Generic Name
```

Each generic name can have more than one strength:
Example:

```
 -TRIMETHOPRIM
  Strengths: 100mg, 200mg
```

There are also times where you can have a generic name that is a combination of two drugs and these two drugs have their strengths, which counts as on strength for this generic name. You can also have multiple.
Example:

```
 -SULFAMETHOXAZOLE & TRIMETHOPRIM
  Strengths: 40mg & 8mg/mL, 400mg & 80mg, 800mg & 160mg
```

So, to enable me keep track of the individual strengths of the combined generic name, i needed another table.

```
GenericTbl(Id, Name, ...)
GenericDetails(Id, GenericId, ...)
Strenghts(Id, GenericDetailsId, Strength, Unit, DosageForm, ...)
```

I hope this helps.

Addition #2
I have changed the ids to integers instead of guid (uniqueidentifier)

```
Pharmacy_GenericDrug
GenericDrugID     GenericDrugName               DrugSubClassificationID     ControlStatusID
1                 TRIMETHOPRIM                  12                          2
2                 SULFAME & TRIMETHOPRIM        4                           1

Pharmacy_GenericDrugDetails
GenericDrugDetailsID       GenericDrugID
1                          1
2                          2



Pharmacy_Strengths
StrengthID         GenericDrugDetailsID       DosageStrength        Unit
1                  1                          200                   mg
2                  2                          80                    mg
3                  2                          8                     mg/L


For the first#1 GenericDrugID = 1: TRIMETHOPRIM | 12 | 200 | mg | 1

For the second#2 GenericDrugID = 2: SULFAME & TRIMETHOPRIM | 4 | 80 | mg | 8 | mg/L | 1

1 > GenericDrugName | DrugSubClassificationID | DosageSrength | Unit | ControlStatusID

2 > GenericDrugName | DrugSubClassificationID | DosageSrength | Unit | DosageSrength | Unit | ControlStatusID
```

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? Concatenate, Min, Max?

Comment: This is really really hard to understand, all these A's B's and C's. Couldn't it be simpler, or a bit more concrete? Can you show the expected result? What do you mean by "merge"? Is this changing data in the database or just writing a query where these data is grouped?

Comment: If you merge the records with c1 = 2 and c1 = 3 into one record, then the fields c2 and c3 must be combined somehow, right? Could you explain why you want to do that? Because the resulting database will not be normalized any more, due to non-atomic values in columns c2 and c3.

Comment: @Astander: I guess its more like joining. Say, 2 | 29 | 2 | b | long | g | short. This should be the result for the record 2 in tbl B.

@Stefan: I will make it clearer in a modification soon.

@Tom: You've got what am talking about. In reality the tables are normalized, it will only be unnormalized in memory (after executing a query).

Comment: could you simply post an example of the values in those tables and the result that you expect after mentioned "merge" operation. Even after your edit it is difficult to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: I just taught about using a cursor. Let my try that and get back to y'all on the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query that merges two rows based on a foreign key (breaks the rule of 1NF).

```
DECLARE @StrengthID INT
DECLARE @GenericDrugDetailsID INT
DEClARE @DosageStrength INT
DECLARE @PresentationUnitID INT
DECLARE @DosageFormID INT
DECLARE @RouteOfAdministrationID INT

DECLARE @nCombinations INT
DECLARE @maxCombinations INT
DECLARE @CurrCombinationTotal INT
DECLARE @CurrGenericDrugDetailsID INT

DECLARE @PName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @DName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @DNameAbbrev VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @RName VARCHAR(100)

DECLARE @GetGenericDrugStrengths CURSOR

SET @nCombinations = 0
SET @CurrGenericDrugDetailsID = 0

--Get the maximum number of combinations
--=====================================================================================
SET @maxCombinations = (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(GenericDrugDetailsID) AS maxCombinations
FROM Pharmacy_Strengths
GROUP BY GenericDrugDetailsID
ORDER BY maxCombinations desc)
--=====================================================================================

--Create a temporary temp to hold the strengths
--=====================================================================================
DECLARE @tmpSQL VARCHAR(max)
SET @tmpSQL = ''

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE NAME LIKE '%tmpStrengths%')
DROP TABLE #tmpStrengths

CREATE TABLE #tmpStrengths (
         StrengthID INT NOT NULL,
         GenericDrugDetailsID INT NOT NULL,
         NumberOfCombinations INT NOT NULL,
         DosageStrength1 INT NOT NULL,
         PresentationUnitID1 INT NOT NULL,
         PresentationUnitName1 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
         DosageFormID1 INT NOT NULL,
         DosageFormName1 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
         DosageFormNameAbbrev1 VARCHAR(50) NULL,
         RouteOfAdministrationID1 INT NOT NULL,
         RouteOfAdministrationName1 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);

             IF (@maxCombinations > 1)
             BEGIN

                 DECLARE @counter int
                 SET @counter = 1                

                 WHILE @counter < @maxCombinations
                 BEGIN
                    SET @counter = @counter + 1
                    SET @tmpSQL = @tmpSQL + 'ALTER TABLE #tmpStrengths ADD StrengthID' + CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' INT NULL;'
                    SET @tmpSQL = @tmpSQL + 'ALTER TABLE #tmpStrengths ADD DosageStrength' + CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' INT NULL;'
                    SET @tmpSQL = @tmpSQL + 'ALTER TABLE #tmpStrengths ADD PresentationUnitID' + CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' INT NULL; '
                    SET @tmpSQL = @tmpSQL + 'ALTER TABLE #tmpStrengths ADD PresentationUnitName' + CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' VARCHAR(100) NULL; '
                    SET @tmpSQL = @tmpSQL + 'ALTER TABLE #tmpStrengths ADD DosageFormID' + CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' INT NULL; '
                    SET @tmpSQL = @tmpSQL + 'ALTER TABLE #tmpStrengths ADD DosageFormName' + CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' VARCHAR(100) NULL; '
                    SET @tmpSQL = @tmpSQL + 'ALTER TABLE #tmpStrengths ADD DosageFormNameAbbrev' + CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' VARCHAR(50) NULL; '
                    SET @tmpSQL = @tmpSQL + 'ALTER TABLE #tmpStrengths ADD RouteOfAdministrationID' + CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' INT NULL; '
                    SET @tmpSQL = @tmpSQL + 'ALTER TABLE #tmpStrengths ADD RouteOfAdministrationName' + CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' VARCHAR(100) NULL; '
                 END
             END
EXEC(@tmpSQL)
--====================================================================================
SET @tmpSQL = ''
SET @GetGenericDrugStrengths = CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT StrengthID, GenericDrugDetailsID, DosageStrength, PresentationUnitID, DosageFormID, RouteOfAdministrationID
    FROM Pharmacy_Strengths
    ORDER BY GenericDrugDetailsID ASC

OPEN @GetGenericDrugStrengths
    FETCH NEXT FROM @GetGenericDrugStrengths INTO @StrengthID, @GenericDrugDetailsID, @DosageStrength, @PresentationUnitID, @DosageFormID, @RouteOfAdministrationID

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        --Get the values of Presentation Unit, Dosage Form, and Route of Administration.
        SELECT @PName = PresentationUnitName
        FROM Pharmacy_PresentationUnit
        WHERE PresentationUnitID = @PresentationUnitID

        SELECT @DName = DosageFormName, @DNameAbbrev = DosageFormNameAbbrev
        FROM Pharmacy_DosageForm
        WHERE DosageFormID = @DosageFormID

        SELECT @RName = RouteOfAdministrationName
        FROM Pharmacy_RouteOfAdministration
        WHERE RouteOfAdministrationID = @RouteOfAdministrationID

        IF (@GenericDrugDetailsID = @CurrGenericDrugDetailsID)
            BEGIN
                SET @nCombinations = (@nCombinations + 1)

                --Alter the temporary table now
                SET @tmpSQL = @tmpSQL + 'UPDATE #tmpStrengths
                    SET StrengthID' + CAST(@nCombinations AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' = ' + CAST(@StrengthID AS VARCHAR(50)) + ',
                        DosageStrength' + CAST(@nCombinations AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' = ' + CAST(@DosageStrength AS VARCHAR(50)) + ',
                        PresentationUnitID' + CAST(@nCombinations AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' = ' + CAST(@PresentationUnitID AS VARCHAR(50)) + ',
                        PresentationUnitName' + CAST(@nCombinations AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' = ''' + CAST(@PName AS VARCHAR(100)) + ''',
                        DosageFormID' + CAST(@nCombinations AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' = ' + CAST(@DosageFormID AS VARCHAR(50)) + ',
                        DosageFormName' + CAST(@nCombinations AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' = ''' + CAST(@DName AS VARCHAR(100)) + ''',
                        DosageFormNameAbbrev' + CAST(@nCombinations AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' = ''' + CAST(@DNameAbbrev AS VARCHAR(50)) + ''',
                        RouteOfAdministrationID' + CAST(@nCombinations AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' = ' + CAST(@RouteOfAdministrationID AS VARCHAR(50)) + ',
                        RouteOfAdministrationName' + CAST(@nCombinations AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' = ''' + CAST(@RName AS VARCHAR(100)) + '''
                    WHERE GenericDrugDetailsID = ' + CAST(@GenericDrugDetailsID AS VARCHAR(50));
                EXEC(@tmpSQL);
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @nCombinations = 1
                SET @CurrGenericDrugDetailsID = @GenericDrugDetailsID;

                --Get the total number of combinations in advance
                SET @CurrCombinationTotal = (SELECT COUNT(GenericDrugDetailsID)
                FROM Pharmacy_Strengths
                WHERE GenericDrugDetailsID = @GenericDrugDetailsID
                GROUP BY GenericDrugDetailsID);

                --Insert in the temporary table now
                INSERT INTO #tmpStrengths (StrengthID, GenericDrugDetailsID, NumberOfCombinations, 
                                    DosageStrength1, PresentationUnitID1, PresentationUnitName1, DosageFormID1, 
                                    DosageFormName1, DosageFormNameAbbrev1, RouteOfAdministrationID1, RouteOfAdministrationName1)
                VALUES (@StrengthID, @GenericDrugDetailsID, @CurrCombinationTotal, @DosageStrength, 
                        @PresentationUnitID, @PName, @DosageFormID, @DName, @DNameAbbrev, @RouteOfAdministrationID, @RName)
            END

        --PRINT CAST(@StrengthID AS varchar(50)) + ' ' + CAST(@GenericDrugDetailsID AS varchar(50)) + ' ' + CAST(@DosageStrength AS varchar(50)) + ' ' + CAST(@PresentationUnitID AS varchar(50)) + ' ' + CAST(@DosageFormID as varchar(50)) + ' ' + CAST(@RouteOfAdministrationID as varchar(50))
        FETCH NEXT FROM @GetGenericDrugStrengths INTO @StrengthID, @GenericDrugDetailsID, @DosageStrength, @PresentationUnitID, @DosageFormID, @RouteOfAdministrationID
    END
    --SELECT * from #tmpStrengths
CLOSE @GetGenericDrugStrengths
DEALLOCATE @GetGenericDrugStrengths

SELECT a.GenericDrugID, 
       a.GenericDrugName,
       f.*,
       a.InsertDate, 
       a.InsertFKUserAccountId, 
       a.UpdateDate, 
       a.UpdateFKUserAccountId, 
       a.Version
FROM Pharmacy_GenericDrug a
INNER JOIN Pharmacy_ControlStatus d ON d.ControlStatusID = a.ControlStatusID
INNER JOIN Pharmacy_GenericDrugDetails e ON e.GenericDrugID = a.GenericDrugID
INNER JOIN #tmpStrengths f ON f.GenericDrugDetailsID = e.GenericDrugDetailsID
ORDER BY GenericDrugName ASC
```

This is what i get before the query:

```
GenericDrugID                        GenericDrugName                                                                                      DrugSubClassificationID              DrugSubClassificationName                                                                                                                                                                                DrugClassificationID                 DrugClassificationName                                                                                                                                                                                   GenericDrugDetailsID DosageStrength PresentationUnitID PresentationUnitName                                                                                 DosageFormID DosageFormName                                                                                       DosageFormNameAbbrev                               RouteOfAdministrationID RouteOfAdministrationName                                                                            ControlStatusID ControlStatusName                                                                                    InsertDate              InsertFKUserAccountId UpdateDate              UpdateFKUserAccountId Version
------------------------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------ -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------ -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------- -------------- ------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------- --------------------- ----------------------- --------------------- -----------------------
83222B76-6690-42F2-BDAD-BE5BD2D19D3B Generic Drug One                                                                                     8ED135ED-5FDB-419A-9C7D-E788A40EAEAC Drug Subclassification Two                                                                                                                                                                               61D618F3-A38A-4416-B0A4-FB29AD614B4B Drug Classification One                                                                                                                                                                                  2                    300            1                  ml                                                                                                   2            Pill                                                                                                 Pill                                               1                       Mouth                                                                                                3               Narcotic                                                                                             2009-10-25 10:10:06.077 1                     2009-11-15 07:06:03.733 1                     2009-10-25 10:10:06.077
83222B76-6690-42F2-BDAD-BE5BD2D19D3B Generic Drug One                                                                                     8ED135ED-5FDB-419A-9C7D-E788A40EAEAC Drug Subclassification Two                                                                                                                                                                               61D618F3-A38A-4416-B0A4-FB29AD614B4B Drug Classification One                                                                                                                                                                                  2                    400            1                  ml                                                                                                   2            Pill                                                                                                 Pill                                               1                       Mouth                                                                                                3               Narcotic                                                                                             2009-10-25 10:10:06.077 1                     2009-11-15 07:06:03.733 1                     2009-10-25 10:10:06.077
83222B76-6690-42F2-BDAD-BE5BD2D19D3B Generic Drug One                                                                                     8ED135ED-5FDB-419A-9C7D-E788A40EAEAC Drug Subclassification Two                                                                                                                                                                               61D618F3-A38A-4416-B0A4-FB29AD614B4B Drug Classification One                                                                                                                                                                                  4                    500            1                  ml                                                                                                   2            Pill                                                                                                 Pill                                               2                       Injection                                                                                            3               Narcotic                                                                                             2009-10-25 10:10:06.077 1                     2009-11-15 07:06:03.733 1                     2009-10-25 10:10:06.077
A1D86FD2-2E65-4F2A-B7A2-7B083B71AB9B Generic Drug Two                                                                                     9925D762-34B8-43B4-A96B-78374F0081B0 Drug Subclassification One                                                                                                                                                                               C10E9F1B-3985-4DB8-8EF8-A6C82B004B9F Drug Classification Two                                                                                                                                                                                  1                    200            1                  ml                                                                                                   2            Pill                                                                                                 Pill                                               1                       Mouth                                                                                                2               None                                                                                                 2009-10-25 10:47:10.623 1                     2009-11-15 04:02:47.890 1                     2009-10-25 10:47:10.623
```

This is what i get now:

```
GenericDrugID                        GenericDrugName                                                                                      DrugSubClassificationID              DrugSubClassificationName                                                                                                                                                                                DrugClassificationID                 DrugClassificationName                                                                                                                                                                                   StrengthID  GenericDrugDetailsID NumberOfCombinations DosageStrength1 PresentationUnitID1 PresentationUnitName1                                                                                DosageFormID1 DosageFormName1                                                                                      DosageFormNameAbbrev1                              RouteOfAdministrationID1 RouteOfAdministrationName1                                                                           StrengthID2 DosageStrength2 PresentationUnitID2 PresentationUnitName2                                                                                DosageFormID2 DosageFormName2                                                                                      DosageFormNameAbbrev2                              RouteOfAdministrationID2 RouteOfAdministrationName2                                                                           InsertDate              InsertFKUserAccountId UpdateDate              UpdateFKUserAccountId Version
------------------------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------ -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------ -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------- ------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ------------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- --------------- ------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ------------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------- --------------------- ----------------------- --------------------- -----------------------
83222B76-6690-42F2-BDAD-BE5BD2D19D3B Generic Drug One                                                                                     8ED135ED-5FDB-419A-9C7D-E788A40EAEAC Drug Subclassification Two                                                                                                                                                                               61D618F3-A38A-4416-B0A4-FB29AD614B4B Drug Classification One                                                                                                                                                                                  2           2                    2                    300             1                   ml                                                                                                   2             Pill                                                                                                 Pill                                               1                        Mouth                                                                                                3           400             1                   ml                                                                                                   2             Pill                                                                                                 Pill                                               1                        Mouth                                                                                                2009-10-25 10:10:06.077 1                     2009-11-15 07:06:03.733 1                     2009-10-25 10:10:06.077
83222B76-6690-42F2-BDAD-BE5BD2D19D3B Generic Drug One                                                                                     8ED135ED-5FDB-419A-9C7D-E788A40EAEAC Drug Subclassification Two                                                                                                                                                                               61D618F3-A38A-4416-B0A4-FB29AD614B4B Drug Classification One                                                                                                                                                                                  4           4                    1                    500             1                   ml                                                                                                   2             Pill                                                                                                 Pill                                               2                        Injection                                                                                            NULL        NULL            NULL                NULL                                                                                                 NULL          NULL                                                                                                 NULL                                               NULL                     NULL                                                                                                 2009-10-25 10:10:06.077 1                     2009-11-15 07:06:03.733 1                     2009-10-25 10:10:06.077
A1D86FD2-2E65-4F2A-B7A2-7B083B71AB9B Generic Drug Two                                                                                     9925D762-34B8-43B4-A96B-78374F0081B0 Drug Subclassification One                                                                                                                                                                               C10E9F1B-3985-4DB8-8EF8-A6C82B004B9F Drug Classification Two                                                                                                                                                                                  1           1                    1                    200             1                   ml                                                                                                   2             Pill                                                                                                 Pill                                               1                        Mouth                                                                                                NULL        NULL            NULL                NULL                                                                                                 NULL          NULL                                                                                                 NULL                                               NULL                     NULL                                                                                                 2009-10-25 10:47:10.623 1                     2009-11-15 04:02:47.890 1                     2009-10-25 10:47:10.623
```

For those interested these are the table structures:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pharmacy_GenericDrug](
        [GenericDrugID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__Pharmacy___Gener__4E53A1AA]  DEFAULT (newid()),
        [GenericDrugName] [varchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
        [DrugSubClassificationID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [ControlStatusID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [InsertDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Pharmacy_GenericDrug_InsertDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
        [InsertFKUserAccountId] [int] NOT NULL,
        [UpdateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Pharmacy_GenericDrug_UpdateDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
        [UpdateFKUserAccountId] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Version] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Pharmacy_GenericDrug_Version]  DEFAULT (getdate())
    )


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pharmacy_GenericDrugDetails](
    [GenericDrugDetailsID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [GenericDrugID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [InsertDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Pharmacy_GenericDrugDetails_InsertDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [InsertFKUserAccountId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Pharmacy_GenericDrugDetails_UpdateDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [UpdateFKUserAccountId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Version] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Pharmacy_GenericDrugDetails_Version]  DEFAULT (getdate())
)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pharmacy_Strengths](
    [StrengthID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [GenericDrugDetailsID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DosageStrength] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PresentationUnitID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DosageFormID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RouteOfAdministrationID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [InsertDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Pharmacy_StrengthCombination_InsertDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [InsertFKUserAccountId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Pharmacy_StrengthCombination_UpdateDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [UpdateFKUserAccountId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Version] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Pharmacy_StrengthCombination_Version]  DEFAULT (getdate())
)



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pharmacy_PresentationUnit](
    [PresentationUnitID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PresentationUnitName] [varchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [InsertDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Pharmacy_PresentationUnit_InsertDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [InsertFKUserAccountId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Pharmacy_PresentationUnit_UpdateDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [UpdateFKUserAccountId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Version] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Pharmacy_PresentationUnit_Version]  DEFAULT (getdate())
)



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pharmacy_DosageForm](
    [DosageFormID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DosageFormName] [varchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [DosageFormNameAbbrev] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [InsertDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Pharmacy_DosageForm_InsertDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [InsertFKUserAccountId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Pharmacy_DosageForm_UpdateDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [UpdateFKUserAccountId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Version] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Pharmacy_DosageForm_Version]  DEFAULT (getdate())
)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pharmacy_RouteOfAdministration](
    [RouteOfAdministrationID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RouteOfAdministrationName] [varchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [InsertDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Pharmacy_RouteOfAdministration_InsertDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [InsertFKUserAccountId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Pharmacy_RouteOfAdministration_UpdateDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [UpdateFKUserAccountId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Version] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Pharmacy_RouteOfAdministration_Version]  DEFAULT (getdate())
)
```

Comment: I would love to know if there any performance implications of using this query.

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's take a stab and see if this gets us anywhere.

Table A:
GenericTbl(Id, Name, ...)

Table B:
GenericDetails(Id, GenericId, ...)

Table C:
Strengths(Id, GenericDetailsId, Strength, Unit, DosageForm, ...)

If when you say merge you're looking for an output set which puts the results together for the strengths of a single generic you could do something along the lines of

```
SELECT
 g.Id,
 g.Name,
 gd.Id,
 s.Strength,
 s.Unit,
 s.OtherFields /*fill in the blanks*/
FROM
 GenericTbl g
  INNER JOIN GenericDetails gd
   on g.Id=gd.GenericId
  INNER JOIN Strengths s
   ON gd.Id=s.GenericDetailsId
ORDER BY
 g.Id, gd.Id, s.Id
```

and that'd give you a single results set listing all the different strengths for each of the generics, grouped their types, with each result on one row.

If what you want is a single row per type with columns to tell you the options available, it should be doable with cursors and temporary tables, or pivots I think from memory.

If what you're actually looking for is for the records to be merged on insert into the database so you only have a single underlying record which contains all the data then you could do it through triggers, but I can't quite see why you'd want to because you'd end up with a 1:1 mapping for B and C and might as well just have them as a single table.

Comment: Thank you very. I did it finally with cursors and a temporary table as you suggested. You could look at the above post as to how i came up with it. Are there any performance implications?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using SQLXML:

```
SELECT  
    STUFF  
    (  
        (  
        SELECT ', ' + cast(id AS NVARCHAR(max)) + ': ' + video  
        FROM Video
        ORDER BY Id  
        FOR XML PATH ('')  
        ),1,1,''  
    )

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Video](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Video] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Views] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

Result:
1: Hulk, 2: Jack, 3: The King

Update:
I also just found [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) at Data Management and Exchange.