# SQL procedure to return the result in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a report, which is developed in SSRS 2005 and i am using a stored procedure to fetch the results from the database.  The result on the report output is very simple as shown below in the figure.

If suppose I am looking for different Members
eg:-

```
 MemberID
c108
c109
c110
...
```

as shown in the figure below.
So for each member there are various USERS and for each user there will be various ROLES.
[image]

But I need all in one row as shown below.

```
MemberID  UserID    Roles
c108   22492   SystemOperator,ItemResearcher,Non-Decision Role,Security Administrator, Decisioning Administrator,Reporting,Corporate Administrator
c108   22469   SystemOperator,ItemResearcher,Non-Decision Role,Security Administrator,Decisioning Administrator
```

So that all roles for each user can be shown in one single row in SSRS (reporting) with ',' seperated.

What is the easiest way to write a stored procedure to produce a result just like this.

Please Note:- There may be some change, if my boss wants me to get the userId also in just 1 row with ',' seperated, then I must be able to modify the query easily.   Please suggest me.  Thank you so much for taking time to read and understand my question.

Comment: Search for [SQL and Pivot](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SQL+pivot) on this site.

Comment: Check this question over here; 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754674/how-do-i-merge-two-or-more-rows-based-on-their-foreign-key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this were MySQL, you'd use the GROUP_CONCAT function to create that comma separated list:

```
SELECT MemberID, UserID, GROUP_CONCAT(Role) AS Roles
FROM myTable
GROUP BY MemberID, UserID
```

However since this is MSSQL you'll need to fake GROUP_CONCAT something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to concatenate then you may want to look at Jeff Moden's article [Performance Tuning: Concatenation Functions and Some Tuning Myths](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Test+Data/61572/) which goes through a variety of techniques.

I would generally use stuff and for XML path (discussed in the article) which looks roughly like:

```
SELECT t1.ID,        
   STUFF((SELECT ','+t2.datafield 
   FROM dbo.tablename2 t2 
                WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')   
FROM dbo.TestData t1  
GROUP BY t1.ID
```

Comment: The idea of using GROUP_Concat is very useful.  Thank you James.